# Is there a reason why my clearInterval function isnt working in React?

Tags: reactjs, timer, clearinterval

I've created a simple timer script initialized with 10 seconds for testing. The problem I'm having is that the pause timer button isn't working as expected.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  const [time, updateTime] = useState(() => { return 10 });
  const [timerRunning, setTimerRunning] = useState(false);
  
  let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;
  let interval;

  function startTimer() {
    setTimerRunning(true);
    interval = setInterval( function() {
      updateTime(previousTime => previousTime === 0 ? previousTime : previousTime - 1);
    }, 1000);
  }

  function pauseTimer() {
    setTimerRunning(false);
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  function restartTimer() {
    setTimerRunning(false);
    updateTime(() => {return 10});
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p>{minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes}:{seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds}</p>
      <button onClick={startTimer}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={pauseTimer}>Pause</button>
      <button onClick={restartTimer}>Restart</button>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I want the pause button to pause the timer. Eventually I'll make conditional statements to have each button appear based on the state of the app and the value of time, but the pause button is my current obstacle.

I first had a separate countdown function which used a conditional to stop the time when the time matched counter **(below)**. I thought of a less complicated way that lets me omit the counter variable **(above)**. Im not sure which option is better, or if either is preventing the *clearInterval* function to work properly. The *clearInterval* function works within the countdown function if statement, but will not work outside of it.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  const [time, updateTime] = useState(() => { return 10 });
  const [timerRunning, setTimerRunning] = useState(false);
  
  let counter = 0;
  let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;
  let interval;

  function countdown() {
    counter++;
    if ( counter === time ) {
       setTimerRunning(false);
       clearInterval(interval);
    }
      updateTime(previousTime => previousTime - 1);
  }
  

  function startTimer() {
    setTimerRunning(true);
    interval = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
  }

  function pauseTimer() {
    setTimerRunning(false);
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  function restartTimer() {
    setTimerRunning(false);
    updateTime(() => {return 10});
  }



  return (
    <>
      <p>{minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes}:{seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds}</p>
      <button onClick={startTimer}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={pauseTimer}>Pause</button>
      <button onClick={restartTimer}>Restart</button>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I would put all the logic in a `useEffect` hook, within which use your `timerRunning` to clear the `setInterval` when it's `false`. Inside the function `puaseTimer` all you have to do is to set the `timerRunning` to false. You would need to include this state variable as a dependency in the dependency array of `useEffect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can't create `let interval;` and assign it a setInterval like `interval = setInterval(countdown, 1000);`

because on each re-render there will be new `let interval;`

what you need to do is create a variable which isn't change on re-redners, you can use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

```
const interval = useRef(null);
.....
function startTimer() {
    interval.current = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
}
....
function pauseTimer() {
   clearInterval(interval.current);
}
```

and I don't think you need `const [timerRunning, setTimerRunning] = useState(false);`

find a [demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-oyhvpe)

Basically when functional component re-renders it will execute from top to bottom, if you use like `let counter = 0;`, then on each re-render it will initialize to 0, if you need to persists your values in each re-renders you might need some [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) (Ex: useState, useRef ...), in this case [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) would do the trick (because you need only one setInterval in each re-renders and useRef will give you the previous value, it will not re-initalize like a general variable)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use useEffect, like this:

```
 const handleStart = () => {
    setChangeValue(true)
  }

  const handlePause = () => {
    setChangeValue(false)
    pauseTimer()
  }

  const handleRestart = () => {
    setInitialState()
    setChangeValue(true)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (changeValue) {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        startTimer()
      }, 100)
      return () => clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }, [changeValue])
```

you have three buttons to start, pause and restart, invoke these  `(handleStart, handlePause, handleRestart)` functions with them

Answer (score 1):

that is my solution

instead of the startTime function, I use useEffect

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    interval = timerRunning && setInterval(() => {
      updateTime(previousTime => previousTime === 0 ? previousTime : previousTime - 1);
    }, 1000);
    return ()=> clearInterval(interval)
  },[timerRunning])
```

and in onClick Start Button

```
<button onClick={()=> setTimerRunning(true)}>Start</button>
```

I hope it is useful